# Close formula for Todd class in terms of Chern classes and Bernoulli numbers

Tags: symmetric-polynomials, characteristic-classes, bernoulli-numbers

Let $\sigma_k$ be the $k$-th elementary symmetric polynomial in $M$ variables $b_i$ and define
$$\prod_{i=1}^M \frac{t b_i} {1-e^{-t b_i}} =:
\sum_{m=0} t^m T_m (b)$$

Of course it's easy to express $T_m(b)$ in terms of $b$ and Bernoulli, but is there a closed formula to write $T_m(b)$ as $T_m(\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_m)$, in terms of Bernoulli and $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_m$, where $\sigma_k = \sigma_k(b)$?

For example, copying from Wikipedia, the first few terms should be
$$ 1 + \frac{\sigma_1}2 + \frac{\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2}{12} + \frac{\sigma_1\sigma_2}{24} + \frac{-\sigma_1^4 + 4\sigma_1^2\sigma_2 + \sigma_1\sigma_3 + 3\sigma_2^2 − \sigma_4}{720} + \ldots$$

Comment: How do you obtain $T_m (\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_m)$ ?

Comment: Writing the series for $\frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$ and equating the coefficients of $f'(t) = f(t) \frac{f'(t)}{f(t)}$  I get something like $j T_j(b) = MT_{j+1}(b)-\sum_{l=0}^j T_{j-l}(b)B_l  \sum_{i=1}^M b_i^{l+1})$

Comment: @user1952009 I clarified what I mean, at least I hope :)